# PYSNMP v3 vs CISCO

Tags: python, snmp, cisco, pysnmp

I'm trying to get an answer from ucs-6100 by SNMP.

Through the console: (analogue of my request)

```
>>> snmpget -v3 -l authPriv -u usr-sha-aes -A authkey1 -X privkey1 -a SHA -x AES demo.snmplabs.com SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0
```

I succeed

But when I use a pysnmp (like this)

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
resp = next(getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
       UsmUserData('usr-sha-aes', 'authkey1', 'privkey1',
                   authProtocol=usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol,
                   privProtocol=usmAesCfb128Protocol),
       UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
       ContextData(),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)))
)
```

(code with these parameters it work)

I always get the answer:

```
Out[20]:(pysnmp.proto.errind.UnknownEngineID('Unknown SNMP engine ID encountered'),
0,
0,
[])
```

I think that's because of the configuration of the protocol.
Is it possible not to send the engine with request?
Or any other design.

Thanks in advance.
python 3.6
pysnmp 4.4.9

---

So, I found where it crashed.

If you have deal with balancers you can have similar issue.
Description:
When we send request through /balancer_host/ from console whith "snmpget" we haven't difference, and we get response from /host_1/ or /host_2/ clearly (direct request to host_1/2 always successful too, but in real situation we dont known host is "balanser" or no, and we dont know which of hosts made responce.)

When we send request through /balancer/ from script whith "pysnmp" we get error 'UnknownEngineID', yes we can try to get  correct EngineID with 'snmp_engine.observer' :

```
observer_context = {}
snmp_engine.observer.registerObserver(
    lambda e, p, v, c: c.update(securityEngineId=v['securityEngineId']), 
    'rfc3412.prepareDataElements:internal',
    cbCtx=observer_context)
auth_data = UsmUserData('non-existing-user')
next(getCmd(snmp_engine, auth_data,
transport_target, ContextData(), ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0))))
print(observer_context['securityEngineId'].prettyPrint())
```

and create correct engine but we nevertheless will get similar issue because we send request to /balancer_host/, with SnmpEngine(EngineID) which was got from /host_1/(for example).
So, test request from observer is working, real request for data - no.
But I am interested to know,  how request work in "snmpget" -  always successful.

Somebody have some ideas how to send request through "balancer" whithout SnmpEngine?

Comment: Different SNMP agents have different settings, and some does require you to specify an engine ID. You have to refer to the agent documentation/manuals for more info, which cannot be answered by SO.

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly - is it that the exact Python code you pasted does not work against `demo.snmplabs.com`? Or does it fail only against cisco?

Comment: I apologize for the incomplete description. 
  
For a clearer description:<br/>
snmpget (console) | demo.snmplabs.com(example) - ok<br/>
pysnmp(script) |  demo.snmplabs.com(example) - ok<br/>
snmpget (console) | cisco device - ok<br>
pysnmp(script) |  cisco device - fail<br>
<br/>
I can not connect in the script only when I call to cisco device